# How to access IDE settings in IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an IntelliJ IDEA plugin that generates inner classes and would like to use the same code style settings as for the default code generation.

How can I access to the common IDE settings (placed in Editor > Code Style > Java -> Code Generation) using IntelliJ IDEA SDK?

Comment: Reformating the piece of code is not enough? `CodeStyleManager.getInstance(project).reformat(psiElement)`

Comment: Yes, it is the only right and recommended solution

Comment: It works, thank you!